# setting a var in smarty with a condition

Tags: php, templates, variables, smarty, var

I really like the [smarty documentation](http://www.smarty.net/documentation) but sometimes its hard to find easy stuff... so heres my question. Is it possible to set a var in a condition? theres a large template with many euro signs.
now there is another new language but they not paying with euro. so instead of settung up a condition for the language around each euro sign. i want to use a var which is set at the start of my template once with the language condition like:

```
{if $lang eq 'ch'}
{*need to set "CHF" as a smarty or php var*}
{else}
{*need to set "EURO" as a smarty or php var*}
{/if}

<div class="payment">{$price} {*CHF or EURO var*}</div>
```

Comment: sorry forgot... its not my plugin/php and maybe its not allowed for me to touch it ;) and all in all... i prefer a smarty solution. thx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
{if $lang eq 'ch'}
    {assign var="currency" value="CHF"}
{else}
    {assign var="currency" value="EURO"}
{/if}

<div class="payment">{$price} {$currency}</div>
```

Comment: nice... didnt know its possible to assign in smarty template itself. will remember it for QAD solutions or if a miss some access rights again ;) thanks works.

Answer (score 3):

Short way:

```
{assign currency ($lang eq 'ch') ? 'CHF' : 'EURO'}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not set it outside the template, in the code, where you assign the price to the template?

I would argue that's where this belongs. Templates are supposed to control the presentation; anything to do with logic belongs in the code driving it.

Comment: ok i tried like i thought... no access to the plugin only to the HTML file...  customers......
so i not even prefer smarty solution.. theres no other way for me right now.

Answer (score 0):

```
{if $lang eq 'ch'}
    <div class="payment">{$price} CHF</div>
{else}
    <div class="payment">{$price} EURO</div>
{/if}
```

There's no need for a variable?

Comment: read the question there are many euro signs on the page (like 40)... and i dont want to do that condition 40 times ;)

Comment: Ah, I overlooked that. Still think this is better done within the php-file itself.