# Smarty php-function inside assing

Tags: php, smarty

Trying to assign but without success:

```
{assign "var_name" {is_numeric($var->test) ? $var->test : ''}}
```

In php it would be like

```
$var_name = is_numeric($var->test) ? $var->test : '';
```

Comment: `without success`...means what? An error? Unexpected behaviour? Please be clear and specific and ensure we have a [mre]

Comment: You can try this solution 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8355913/setting-a-var-in-smarty-with-a-condition

Comment: Thanks, Tejas! One of the solutions from there works: {assign var_name {(is_numeric($var->test)) ? $var->test : ''}}

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this:

```
{assign var_name {(is_numeric($var->test)) ? $var->test : ''}}
```